# SQL Query not getting executing - returns empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with date field whose data type is also date and i want to fetch those recods which lie betwnn two dates.

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry  WHERE date_in >=2012-02-08 && date_in<=2012-02-27
```

i also tried

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry WHERE date_in  BETWEEN 2012-02-08 AND 2012-02-27
```

i have records in table with date `2012-02-14` but still it return empty value.

Please help me guiding what i am missing exactly.

Comment: Are you missing quotes? 2012-02-08 == 2002

Comment: Any chance you could show us your table's field list and data types? And a few of the rows, some in the date range and some not. Also, if you just do SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry do you get all rows back as expected? (Should SQL dates not be formatted as #yyyy mm dd#?)

Comment: @JTeagle - Different flavours of SQL have different ways of representing date data-types.  One thing that is *reasonably* universal is to use a string data-type and allow it to be implicitly converted to a date data-type.  That has it's own pitfalls (`'01-Jan-2012'` won't work in France, etc), but `'20120101'` is pretty common practice

Comment: @Dems - Thanks - valuable information, I did not know this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes round your dates:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry WHERE date_in BETWEEN '2012-02-08' AND '2012-02-27'
```

Without the quotes your dates are treated as arithmetic expressions: 2012-02-08 = 2002.

The query you posted is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry WHERE date_in BETWEEN 2002 AND 1983
```

Answer (score 5):

`2012-02-08` isn't a date, it's an integer calulation that yield the result `2002`.  This is then implictly cast into a date, with `2002` meaning `2002 days from the base date`

Instead, use `'2012-02-08'` which is a string, which is also implicitly cast into a date, but the one you want.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry WHERE date_in BETWEEN '2012-02-08' AND '2012-02-27'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_races_entry WHERE date_in>= '2012-02-08 00:00:00' and date_in<= '2012-02-27 00:00:00'
```

Comment: it's a DATE field, not a DATETIME field. Therefore false.

Comment: And the OPs `>=` and `<=` have spontaneously changed to `>` and `<` for no apparent reason.